What is a Novardok "Vaad asiri kodesh"?
What is (was?) exactly a Vaad Asiri Kodesh [וועד עשירי קודש] in the context of Novardok Musarists?
Could it be a collective moment too or was it just a time for individual introspection?
Thanks!

It is a systemised approach to self-improvement through the taking on of kabbalos (personal targets geared towards further refining a person's spiritual attainment).
According to here it is defined as follows:

א) כל קבלה שמקבל על עצמו, לעשרה ימים בלבד.
ב) ביום העשירי קודש (בתאריכים: א' י' כ') בודק הקבלה אם לשנות או להוסיף וכו', או להשאיר חלק מהקבלה ולהמשיך בקבלה אחרת.
ג) במשך העשרה ימים יעסוק בעניין הקבלה. כגון אם קיבל להתחזק באמירת ברכה מסוימת, יתבונן בפירוש הברכה וענינה. או אם קיבל להתחזק בעניין התורה, יתבונן וירחיב בערך התורה, וכו'.
ד) לכתחילה יעסוק תקופה (כגון חודש) בעניין אחד, ובאותו נושא יקבל קבלות שונות.
ה) בתחילה יקבל קבלות היותר קלות לקיימם. (עי' אור ישראל אגרות ז', ח', ט"ו).
ו)  כשמקבלים כמה חברים ביחד יש בזה תועלת שכ"א מוסיף עצות, והמחייב יותר חזק לזכור ולקיים הקבלות.
ז) הקיום העיקרי לעניין הקבלות, לכתוב איך הצליח בזה בכל יום ואיך יוכל לשפר וכו', ויחשוב על עצות להזכיר הקבלות ולחזקם ויכתבם.

Any kabbala that he accepts, for ten days only.

On the 10th holy day (dates: 1 10 20) he examines the Kabbalah, whether to change or add, etc., or to leave part of the Kabbalah and continue with another Kabbalah.

For the duration of the ten days he will deal with the Kabbalah. For example, if he accepted to be strengthened by saying a bracha properly, he will look at the interpretation of the bracha and its purpose. Or, if he accepted to be strengthened in the matter of the Torah, he will observe and expand on the value of the Torah, etc.

To begin with, he will deal with one matter for a period (such as a month), and in the same matter he will accept other kabbalos.

Initially he will accept kabbalos that are easier to maintain. (cit. Ohr Yisrael, Igros 7, 8, 15).

When you receive several friends together, there is a benefit in that everyone adds advice, and the obligation is stronger to remember and keep the kabbalos.

The main matter regarding kabbalos, is to write how he succeeded in this every day and how he could improve, etc., and he will think of tips to remember the kabbalos and strengthen them and write them down.




I agree with this answer, but I would have split it in two. Most of this definition is simply the definition of a Vaad. As in https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/49216/whats-a-musar-vaad-and-why-is-it-called-that it is really only the scheduling piece that it distinxtly the Novhardoker "Asiri Qodesh" piece. Likely cultural and connotation differences in how a Vaad resonated in Kelm or Slabodka in contrast to Novhardok. But it is. Or captures in this text. Nor do I know enough to describe it either.

Is it actually only the scheduling that distinguish a Vaad from a Vaad Asiri Kodesh?
The Vaad, at least in Novardok, exists as a group beside its physical meetings. Does the Vaad Asiri Kodesh group coincide with the Vaad one? Is it just a special meeting of the normal Vaad, or it is a more (or less) extended session?
Thanks!

A vaad just means a "gathering". In Yeshiva terms, a vaad is group of bochurim who come together often to receive a "shmuess" from a Rebbi as a means to help them grow etc. Like the definition it is a gathering of bochurim who are coming together to collectively work on something within a systemised framework.
